# Can I set a FullText Stoplist to be the default stoplist for all FullText Indexes in a Database in MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database with a number of tables, many of them with Fulltext Indexes.
I want to create a new Fulltext Stoplist to apply to all of these tables in the database. Is there a way to set a Stoplist to be the default for all Fulltext Indexes in a specific database?

By setting it as default I would assume this also assigns any new Fulltext Indexes to that default Stoplist. If this is not the case I would also like to know how to set this up.

I can always update each Fulltext Index one at a time however this is time-consuming and leaves room for error/potential to miss one.

I have tried looking at the MS T-SQL help pages eg. CREATE FULLTEXT STOPLIST/ALTER FULLTEXT STOPLIST, CREATE/ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX  and any questions previously asked however I can't find any reference to whether this is actually possible or not.

Any help is greatly appreciated, also this is my first question posted so please let me know if i've missed something.

Comment: If you change the stop word list, you will still need to rebuild all the indexes.

Comment: @GordonLinoff would they all need to be run separately? I guess I had assumed I could rebuild a catalog all at once or at least set up a job to rebuild the indexes one after the other